# I Can not view category without login

Tags: prestashop-1.7

Nice to meet you all, sorry my english is bad.

I just wanna ask this question:

How to view product without login in Prestashop 1.7 ?

I try to click a category on my prestashop website without account login, but i can not view any products. Message is "You don't have acces to this category"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your categories access is limited by groups.

Go to **Catalog->Categories**, edit the required categories and select checkboxes with your customer groups. Save changes.

Check the screenshot:

http://prntscr.com/otwshc